# HTTP Post to PHP script hosted on unauthenticated FTP server

Tags: http, ftp

Is it possible to create a HTTP POST that posts to the PHP script that is hosted on a separate unauthenticated FTP server?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

No.

POST is [an HTTP method](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), and HTTP requests have [a specific protocol structure](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html).  FTP, being an entirely different protocol, has [an entirely different structure](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/ftp.htm).

FTP servers don't understand HTTP requests, and HTTP servers don't understand FTP requests.  (One "server" can handle both, and in such a case would be acting as two distinct services from the perspective of any consuming client.)

If the target page is hosted as a file on an FTP server, then there is no HTTP endpoint to receive the request.  There's just a file.